# Access computer that has no password via network

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts, file-sharing

I'm trying to access my desktop files through my laptop. Both are connected to the same network.

I go to Network and see my desktop computer there. I double click and try to access my files there however I'm prompted with a Username and Password. I know the username, however since my desktop has no password I don't know what to put. I've tried putting a blank password but it's not giving me access.

I've tried the other way around (accessing my laptop files through my desktop) which is working, only difference is that my laptop has a password and so all I had to do was enter it.

Any advice?

Comment: By default, Windows blocks all non-local logins to accounts that don't have passwords, for security reasons. Set a password or poke around in `secpol.msc`. Someone else might write a proper answer...

Comment: you could add both machines to a homegroup and share files on the home group, that way you should be able to share files without having to setup the password

Comment: @Shakehar yeah I'm actually trying to see if I can do this without a homegroup. This will do for now I guess

Comment: When you are prompted for the username and password, have you tried entering the user name in the following format; `machine_name\user_name`?

Comment: @canadmos: Yes sir I've tried this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on the same workgroup network, you can create similar user accounts on windows with no password, logon with same account names on both computers and access shared folders.

If not possible, you should create a passworded account on desired machine, so shared folders on it would be accessible through that account on other workgroup machines.

Another option is to create DFS or FTP. FTP is much simpler and profitable in similar scenarios. Try using FileZilla.

https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=server

https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client